# Twitter4j TwitterStream or BufferReading causing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space

Tags: java, memory-leaks, twitter4j, heap-memory

This is my first Stackoverflow post, sorry if it's not great. Feedback will definitely help!

I'm currently running into a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap space` problem with a project I'm working on using the Twitter Streaming API.

The error comes up after streaming in around 500 - 1000 tweets and I can't pinpoint what is causing it to occur.

In the `onStatus` method for the `StatusListener` I have the following code:

```
public void onStatus(Status status) {

        tweetCount++;
        System.out.println("Tweet #" + tweetCount);

        String statusInfo = status.getText().replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\r", "");

        String usersCountry = getTweetUserLocation(status);
        status = null;

        if(!usersCountry.equals("INVALID_LOCATION")){
           countryList.updateWhoTalkedAboutWho(usersCountry, statusInfo);
        }

        try {
           Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           System.out.println("Exception in onStatus() catch block");
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

Could the error be caused by the speed at which the status are coming in? I can see why it would take up more memory if status are coming in much faster than they are being processed.

The other suspect is the `BufferReader`, here is the code:

```
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
       conn.getInputStream()));
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String line;

while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}

rd.close();
rd=null;
result = sb.toString();
```

Please let me know if you have an idea why the `OutOfMemoryError` is occurring. If you want to see the entire code, please check out my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/xDranik/TwitterResearch)

Here is the stack trace after hitting the Error:

```
Exception in thread "Twitter Stream consumer-1[Receiving stream]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:515)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:306)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:333)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
at twitter4j.StatusStreamBase.handleNextElement(StatusStreamBase.java:85)
at twitter4j.StatusStreamImpl.next(StatusStreamImpl.java:57)
at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$TwitterStreamConsumer.run(TwitterStreamImpl.java:478)
Exception in thread "Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.io.BufferedReader.<init>(BufferedReader.java:80)
at java.io.BufferedReader.<init>(BufferedReader.java:91)
at TweetCountry.sendGetRequest(TweetCountry.java:75)
at TweetCountry.findCountryName(TweetCountry.java:28)
at StreamTweets.getTweetUserLocation(StreamTweets.java:135)
at StreamTweets.access$4(StreamTweets.java:115)
at StreamTweets$1.onStatus(StreamTweets.java:45)
at twitter4j.StatusStreamImpl.onStatus(StatusStreamImpl.java:75)
at twitter4j.StatusStreamBase$1.run(StatusStreamBase.java:114)
at twitter4j.internal.async.ExecuteThread.run(DispatcherImpl.java:116)
```

Comment: how about increasing the heap memory of your IDE editing the .ini file

Comment: The program is going to be left on for quite a while, so thousands of status's will be coming in. Increasing the heap memory won't help with that

Comment: Whoever down voted... how about leaving some feedback next time?

Comment: @xDranik You should add the full stack trace of the `OutOfMemoryError` to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jonathan! I'll add the full stack trace later on today (If i haven't already found the reason)

Answer (score 2):

I now know what I was doing wrong!
The onStatus() method in the status listener should be (at most) storing the incoming status information instead of processing. I'll be using two programs this time, one for populating a DB or file with the status information, and another to process that data.